# Why does the screen render old pixels?

Tags: python, pygame

Hey don't really know how to phrase this question better but what i'm getting is basically the thing you see when you go out of bounds in any source games... And I think I found the code that causes it but I dont know why or how to fix it...

Anyways here's a picture of how it looks:

[Image of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzcua.png)

Here's the code bit that I think causes it:

```
 self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.display, self.screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
```

If you think its anything else it the code, here's the full file:

```
 import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.mouse import get_pos

from utils import button, constants
from entities import player, point, flag
import game


class Game():

    def __init__(self, map_number):
            pygame.init()
            self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            self.display = pygame.Surface((300,300))
            self.font_small = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)
            self.font_medium = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)
            self.test_bg = pygame.image.load('images/wp.png')
            self.pause = False

            self.flag_mover = False

            self.map_number = map_number

            f = open('maps/map'+self.map_number+'.txt')
            self.map_data = [[int(c) for c in row] for row in f.read().split('\n')]
            f.close()

            #Tile list -----
            self.spawn_img = pygame.image.load('images/spawn.png').convert()
            self.spawn_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

            self.goal_img = pygame.image.load('images/goal.png').convert()
            self.goal_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))


            self.key_img = pygame.image.load('images/key.png').convert()
            self.key_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

            self.lava_img = pygame.image.load('images/lava.png').convert()
            self.lava_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

            self.grass_img = pygame.image.load('images/grass2.png').convert()
            self.grass_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
            
            #Player
            for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                    if tile == 1:
                        self.player = player.Player(self.display, (150 + (x+1) * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + (y-0.5) * 5), self.map_data)

            #goal flag
            for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                    if tile == 2:
                        self.goal_flag = flag.Flag(self.display, (150 + (x+1) * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + (y-1) * 5), self.map_data, self.player)

            #points
            self.point_list = []
            for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                    if tile == 3:
                        self.points = point.Point(self.display, (150 + (x+1) * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + (y-0.5) * 5), self.map_data)
                        self.point_list.append(self.points)

            self.running = True
            self.click = False

    
    def drawText(self, text, font, color, surface, x, y):
        textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.topleft = (x, y)
        surface.blit(textobj, textrect)


    def gameLoop(self):
        
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        if self.pause == False:
                            self.pause = True
                        else:
                            self.pause = False

            if self.pause == False:
                # self.screen.blit(self.test_bg, (0,0))
                self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.display, self.screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
                self.drawText('game', self.font_small, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, 20, 20)
                
                #Draws the map
                for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                    for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                        if tile == 0:
                            self.display.blit(self.lava_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 1:
                            self.display.blit(self.spawn_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 2:
                            self.display.blit(self.goal_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 3:
                            self.display.blit(self.key_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))    
                        if tile == 4:
                            self.display.blit(self.grass_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))

                #collision detection between entities
                if self.goal_flag.rect[0] == self.player.rect[0] and self.goal_flag.rect[1] == self.player.rect[1] - 2:
                    self.flag_mover = True
                if self.flag_mover == True:
                    self.goal_flag.rect[1] += -0.1
                        
                     
                    

                #update
                for points in self.point_list:
                    points.update()
                self.goal_flag.update()
                self.player.update()
                
                
                #draw


                # self.display.blit(self.screen, (0,0))
                # pygame.display.update()
                # pygame.display.flip()
                # self.clock.tick(60)

            else:
                self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.display, self.screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
                self.drawText('game', self.font_small, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, 20, 20)
                self.drawText('PAUSED', self.font_medium, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, pygame.display.Info().current_w/2-50, pygame.display.Info().current_h/2)
                
                for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                    for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                        if tile == 0:
                            self.display.blit(self.lava_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 1:
                            self.display.blit(self.spawn_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 2:
                            self.display.blit(self.goal_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 3:
                            self.display.blit(self.key_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))       
                        if tile == 4:
                            self.display.blit(self.grass_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
              
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: @marienbad No. It would be better to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The github repository will change and the question will become not verifiable in the future. Never ask new contributors to add off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self.display` *Surface* is created just once in the constructor and reused in every frame. Therefore you need to clear the `self.display` *Surface* before drawing on it.

Use [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to clear `self.display` after you `blit` it on the screen:

```py
self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.display, self.screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
self.display.fill(0)
```