# Why does the text get scaled?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to move a text alongside the player character but it gets scaled weird...
Here's a picture of the player character alongside the text "test":

[image: Text in game]

It should be some kind of antialiasing since that is off in the code for the moving text:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


class MovingText(): 
 
    def __init__(self, text, font_size, color, surface, target, off_1, off_2): 
        self.font       = pygame.font.SysFont(None, font_size)
        self.textobj    = self.font.render(text, 0, color) 
        self.textrect   = self.textobj.get_rect()
        self.surface    = surface  
        self.target     = target 
        self.offset     = (off_1, off_2)
        self.textrect.center = self.target_pos() 
         
    def update(self): 
        self.textrect.center = self.target_pos() 
        self.surface.blit(self.textobj, self.textrect.center)
         
    def target_pos(self): 
        pos = self.target.rect.center 
        return pos[0] + self.offset[1], pos[1] + self.offset[0]
```

What I think is causing the problem is either when the text gets created, here:

```
self.follow_text = movingtext.MovingText('test', 10, (255, 255, 255), self.display, self.player, 10, 5)
```

If you think it's something else you're free to check the rest of the code out, don't really think that but i've been proven wrong once or twice:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.mouse import get_pos

import time

from utils import button, constants, movingtext
from entities import player, entity
import game


class Game():

    def __init__(self, map_number):
            pygame.init()
            self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            self.display = pygame.Surface((300,300))
            self.font_small = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)
            self.font_medium = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)
            self.test_bg = pygame.image.load('images/wp.png')
            self.pause = False

            self.timer = 0
            self.game_called = time.time()

            self.flag_mover = False

            self.map_number = map_number

            f = open('maps/map'+self.map_number+'.txt')
            self.map_data = [[int(c) for c in row] for row in f.read().split('\n')]
            f.close()

            #Tile list -----
            self.spawn_img = pygame.image.load('images/spawn.png').convert()
            self.spawn_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

            self.goal_img = pygame.image.load('images/goal.png').convert()
            self.goal_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))


            self.key_img = pygame.image.load('images/key.png').convert()
            self.key_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

            self.lava_img = pygame.image.load('images/lava.png').convert()
            self.lava_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

            self.grass_img = pygame.image.load('images/grass2.png').convert()
            self.grass_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
            
            #Player
            for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                    if tile == 1:
                        self.player = player.Player(self.display, (150 + (x+1) * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + (y-0.5) * 5), self.map_data)

            #goal flag
            for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                    if tile == 2:
                        self.goal_flag = entity.Entity(self.display, (150 + (x+1) * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + (y-1) * 5), 'images/goal_flag.png')

            #points
            self.point_list = []
            for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                    if tile == 3:
                        self.points = entity.Entity(self.display, (150 + (x+1) * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + (y-0.5) * 5),'images/point.png')
                        self.point_list.append(self.points)

            self.running = True
            self.click = False

    
    def drawText(self, text, font, color, surface, x, y):
        textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.topleft = (x, y)
        surface.blit(textobj, textrect)


    def gameLoop(self):
        
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        if self.pause == False:
                            self.pause = True
                        else:
                            self.pause = False

            if self.pause == False:
        
                self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.display, self.screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
                self.display.fill(0) #clears the scree
                self.drawText('game', self.font_small, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, 20, 20)
                # self.drawText('time: '+str(int(self.timer/1000)), self.font_small, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, self.player.rect[0], self.player.rect[1]) 

                self.follow_text = movingtext.MovingText('test', 10, (255, 255, 255), self.display, self.player, 10, 5)
                # self.follow_text = movingtext.MovingText()

                #Draws the map
                for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                    for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                        if tile == 0:
                            self.display.blit(self.lava_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 1:
                            self.display.blit(self.spawn_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 2:
                            self.display.blit(self.goal_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 3:
                            self.display.blit(self.key_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))    
                        if tile == 4:
                            self.display.blit(self.grass_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))

                #collision detection between entities
                if self.goal_flag.rect[0] == self.player.rect[0] and self.goal_flag.rect[1] == self.player.rect[1] - 2:
                    self.flag_mover = True
                if self.flag_mover == True:
                    self.goal_flag.rect[1] += -0.1
                

                #point collision
                for point_collision in self.point_list:
                    if point_collision.rect[0] == self.player.rect[0] and point_collision.rect[1] == self.player.rect[1]:
                        self.point_list.remove(point_collision)
                        
        
                #update
                for points in self.point_list:
                    points.update()
                self.goal_flag.update()
                self.player.update()
                self.follow_text.update()

            else:
                self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.display, self.screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
                self.drawText('game', self.font_small, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, 20, 20)
                self.drawText('PAUSED', self.font_medium, (255, 255, 255), self.screen, pygame.display.Info().current_w/2-50, pygame.display.Info().current_h/2)
                
                for y, row in enumerate(self.map_data):
                    for x, tile in enumerate(row):
                        if tile == 0:
                            self.display.blit(self.lava_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 1:
                            self.display.blit(self.spawn_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 2:
                            self.display.blit(self.goal_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                        if tile == 3:
                            self.display.blit(self.key_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))       
                        if tile == 4:
                            self.display.blit(self.grass_img, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
              

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Do you draw the text on a surface and scale the entire surface? (as in your previous question [Why does the screen render old pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654590/why-does-the-screen-render-old-pixels)). When the surface is scaled, the text is scaled with the surface.

Comment: Ah well hello again... Yes that does make sense haha and thanks again for the help my friend!

Answer (score 0):

The text is scaled as you draw the text on a surface and scale the surface to the size of your window. You have to draw the text on the display surface directly.